# Why does using Python's '-i' or '-c' options cause readline history from previous sessions to be unavailable?

Tags: python, readline

I'm using a `.pythonsetup` file to enable readline history in the manner described in the [readline module docs](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/readline.html#example). Normally, history from previous interactive interpreter sessions is available when I start up a new session.

```
% python
>>> # history available...
```

However, when using -i or -c, past history is not available. It's not that readline is disabled: history is available for the current session, but that history will not be saved to the history file.

```
% python -i myscript.py
>>> # previous history not available

% python -i -c "x = 1"
>>> # previous history not available
```

This behavior is consistent in Python 2.6, 2.7, and 3.2.

Does anyone know why previous readline history is disabled when using -i or -ic? Is there is a way to configure readline to make history available (and savable) when using -i or -ic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The man page for my `python2.6` says

> -i ... It does not read the $PYTHONSTARTUP file.

Since this is how you customized the readline behavior ( http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/readline.html#example ), it doesn't take effect when you use that option.

Comment: It sure does -- I missed that. This clarifies that my Pythons have readline enabled; it's the history bit that I'm enabling with <code>.pythonstartup</code>. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can get this behavior if you use [IPython](http://ipython.org/):

```
ipython -i myscript.py
```

Personally, I'd recommend using it anyways, for a vast number of reasons it's superior to the default interpreter.

Comment: Yes, I do use iPython. I ran across this issue when doing some Python 3.2 development. The Python 3 branch of iPython requires manual installation, which I haven't tried yet. Still, I'd never noticed the behavior before and thought someone else might know.

Comment: `easy_install-3.2 http://archive.ipython.org/release/0.11/py3/ipython-0.11-py3.zip`

Comment: Grin. So easy. (Under Ubuntu Natty, the command is easy_install3.)